# C# reference MathCAD API - external DLL

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am writing simple Windows Forms application that needs to use MathCAD API, to do some batch processing of MathCAD files.

Wrote this application, but for now it uses default path to DLL

`"using Ptc.MathcadPrime.Automation;"`
path in properties of above dll is set in Assemblies to:

```
C:\Program Files\PTC\Mathcad Prime 9.0.0.0\Ptc.MathcadPrime.Automation.dll
```

So as I understand this path is hardcoded into my program, but what if I would install MathCAD in different directory or use program on another computer where it is installed on different drive?

Can I add path to this DLL in the `app.config` file, so there is a check done when application starts?

I added config file, where the path may be specified:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="mcadPathDLL" value="C:\Program Files\PTC\Mathcad Prime 9.0.0.0\Ptc.MathcadPrime.Automation.dll"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I retrieve the value from app config but where to define it in the program, so it knows where the DLL is to be taken from?

```
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  var McadPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mcadPathDLL"];
  MessageBox.Show(McadPath);
}
```

EDIT: In `Program.cs` I do as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BatchProcessor
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        
        private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            string dllLocation = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mcadPathDLL"];
            if (File.Exists(dllLocation))
            {
                return Assembly.LoadFrom(dllLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Path to MathCAD API dll is wrong. Please define correct path in 'app.config' to 'Ptc.MathcadPrime.Automation.dll' file and re-run the application" +
                    "Program will close now");
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Code is going through this part, with no errors so far, but what I supposed want to see and use in `MainWindow.cs` is `using Ptc.MathcadPrime.Automation;`.

Looks that program does is not seeing above `dll`. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are allowed to redistribute the dll.

I cannot tell if this applies to MathCAD, but for some SDKs you include and redistribute the .Net dll with your application. For example by copying the dll to your repository before adding it as an reference.

Such a .Net dll should then hopefully then ensure it can load *its* dependencies as long as the application is installed on the computer, regardless of where it is installed.

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, meaning, I do not want to redistribute the *.dll because it is not mine. I just want to add link to this library, so the program will work only when you have your own copy of MathCAD installed on your computer.

Comment: @BlackbeardThePirate If you have permission to redistribute it it would not matter if it is not yours. It is fairly likely that the dll is a thin wrapper around files installed by MathCAD. Ifit is not usable without the full application the authors might not mind if you redistribute it. But check the documentation.

Comment: That's true, nevertheless I want to solve the problem anyway for the future :)